# Unwanted button painting on Panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

So I am making a simple paint program, and I have two panels. The first panel is center right and is the canvas. The other, docked on the right and is to hold tool buttons, but it currently has only a clear button. The thing is when I start clicking on the canvas, the clear button is painted on it as a result. Any idea what  I am missing?

```
public class Paint extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private JButton clear;
    private JPanel tools;

    Paint(){
        canvas= new Canvas();
       add(canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);
         clear= new JButton("Clear");
         clear.addActionListener(this);
         tools= new JPanel();
         tools.add(clear);
         add(tools,BorderLayout.WEST);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getSource()==clear){
           canvas.clear();
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setSize(1000,800);
        paint.setVisible(true);
        paint.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   
}
```

Canvas:

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private int x= -10;
    private int y= -10;
    private boolean clear=false; 
    Canvas(){
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                x=e.getX();
                y=e.getY();
                draw();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
          @Override
          public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
              x=e.getX();
              y=e.getY();
              draw();
           } 
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       if(clear){
           super.paintComponent(g);
           clear=false;
       }
       else{
           g.fillOval(x,y,4,4);
       }


    }

    public void draw(){
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void clear(){
        clear=true;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Graphics` is a shared resources, that is, every component that is painted during a paint cycle uses the same `Graphics` context.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting by the component, failing to call `super.paintComponent` EVERY TIME `paintComponent` is called is leaving what ever was previously painted to the `Graphics` context in tact.

Call `super.paintComponent` every time `paintComponent` is called.

Painting in Swing is destructive, that is, you are expected to repaint the entire state of your component whenever `paintComponent` is called.